Pytorch Lightning Progress Bar New Line
I would like to have each epoch to be displayed on new line so I can observe the progress instead of using the same line at default behavior.
One of the suggestions was to use leave=True at TQDM, which didn't work.

To use RichProgressBar instead to TQDM
from lightning.pytorch.callbacks import RichProgressBar

trainer = L.Trainer(max_epochs=4, accelerator='gpu',
                        num_nodes=1, 
                        log_every_n_steps=1,
                        val_check_interval=10,
                        callbacks=[RichProgressBar(leave=True)]
                    )


